# React dangerouslySetInnerHTML printing out '[object Object]'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have my element:

```
dangerouslySetInnerHTML: { __html: this.props.html.map(React.renderToStaticMarkup).join('') }
```

`this.props.html` is an array of React Elements (built up from this method):

```
makeOutput(model) {
    return <Key model={model} />;
}
```

When I run my code above in a breakpoint, I do get:

```
> this.props.html.map(React.renderToStaticMarkup).join('')
> "<span>b</span>"
```

However, when the element is output to the DOM, all that's shown is `[object Object]`. Any reason for this?

Comment: Can you provide a **complete** example?

Comment: I ran into the same problem. For me it was because the server-side renderer needed to be restarted to do it's thing. Once I did that, the HTML was rendered as expected in the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/ua5rafdg/) shows that the technique works with no problem:

```
function makeOutput(text) {
  return <Wrapper text={text} />;
}

var Wrapper = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return <div>Wrapping: {this.props.text}</div>
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render() {
    var items = [
      makeOutput("one"),
      makeOutput("two"),
      makeOutput("three")
    ];
    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: items.map(React.renderToStaticMarkup).join("") }} />
    );
  }
});

React.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

The problem must lie in some code you haven't yet revealed.

Comment: Do the double curly braces make a difference?  `{{__html...  }}`.

Comment: In JSX, the outer curlies are for a JS expression as a prop; the inner are there because that value is an object literal.

Comment: They deprecated this method on the `React` object and added to the `ReactDOMServer` object. Need to include `react-dom-server.js` or require `react-dom/server`.

Answer (score 1):

Try by convert your HTML to string type

```js
// before
const content = <p>Hello</p>

// after update
const content = `<p>Hello</p>`

// implementation
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: content }} />
```